# How to use NSWindowController class

Tags: objective-c, xib, nswindowcontroller

I am sorry if this seems trivial, but I am sure its a reasonable question to ask here.
I worked a lot around the `NSWindowController` class, and it seems the only way to get it
to work fully (for my purpose), is by creating a new xib-file along with it.

My question is, would it be somehow feasible to work with `MainMenu.xib` and the `NSWindowController` class and an instantiated object controller, to get interaction with the windows' content. So far without xib the only code segments getting executed are within `awakeFromNib`. The purpose being, I want to save xib-file space, complexity and have it easily integrate with a bigger project. Just fyi this is not a document-based project.
Should I choose a different subclass of NSObject other than `NSWindowController`? Or is it not possible?

The code required to run for the class to be working fully is as follows:

```
- (void) tableViewSelectionDidChange:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    NSInteger selectedRow = [logsTableView selectedRow];


    if ([directoryList containsObject:[directoryList objectAtIndex:selectedRow]])
    {   
        NSString *logContent = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:[directoryList objectAtIndex:selectedRow]
                                                     encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding
                                                        error:NULL];

        if (logContent != NULL)
        {
            [logsTextView setString:logContent];
        } else
        {
            [logsTextView setString:@"No permission to read log"];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you think that adding a separate .xib file will add significantly to size or complexity, or make integration more difficult? I doubt that any of those concerns are valid.

Comment: OK perhaps not significantly to the size of the application but to the resource usage, I mean xib-files have to be loaded each separately right? I am sure a cumulative xib-file loading is far more efficient.

Comment: It's generally more efficient to have separate xibs. If everything is in one xib, then everything in that xib is loaded when that xib is loaded. Xib/nib loading is an all or nothing affair. You're not saving anything really by avoiding a xib in your project. Most apps have quite a few.

Comment: I recommend this article: https://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2013-04-05-windows-and-window-controllers.html

Comment: Interesting read thanks @KenThomases

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`NSWindowController` usually wants to create the window it controls, which means you either need to give it a XIB file that contains the window to create or override the various window creation methods to customize the window in code. So it's probably not feasible to use an already-instantiated window from a different XIB with your `NSWindowController`.

That said, I almost always create a a XIB and an `NSWindowController` subclass for every window in my apps. Even the preferences window gets its own window controller class. The only exception would be extremely simple windows, but even now I'm struggling to think of a good example.

Your method isn't being called because window controller instance isn't set as the table view's `delegate`. The typical pattern here is to create your window in a XIB, set your window controller as the custom class of the File's Owner object, and then hook up the table view's `delegate` and `dataSource` outlets to File's Owner. This makes your window controller the table view's data source and delegate, and the connections will be established automatically when the XIB is loaded.

Comment: Thanks @Alex for your answer. I am really skeptical of using a xib for each window, it probably depends on the purpose, but I figure its a waste of resources and loading time.

Comment: Three things: 1) don't worry about premature optimization and 2) XIBs are extremely fast to load. They are serialized representations of your object graph. Any time cost would come from constructing the objects in the file, which would happen no matter which way you go. And 3) This is a cleaner architecture which will be easier to maintain over the long haul.

Comment: Thanks @Alex for all your experience, that was really helpful, now can consciously create as many xib files as I want :)